# Python 2 to Python 3 Conversion of http Request

Tags: python, http, python-3.x, python-2.x, python-3.3

I am new to Python. I am trying to convert Python 2 code to Python 3. In my old code I have the following lines:

```
# Create a cookiejar to store cookie
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
# Create opener
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
```

I have converted these lines to:

```
# Create a cookiejar to store cookie
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
# Create opener
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
```

The issue I have is that I keep getting the following error:
NameError: global name 'cookielib' is not defined

I am not sure what I am doing wrong and how to fix this. Can someone please help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: I have tried to convert the line to cj=http.cookieJar.CookieJar() but this gives an attribute error that the 'module' object has no attribute 'cookieJar'.

Answer (score 1):

Did you use the [`2to3`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html) tool? Also, using Python Docs,

> Note The cookielib module has been renamed to http.cookiejar in Python
>   3. The 2to3 tool will automatically adapt imports when converting your sources to Python 3.

After seeing your comment, the problem is that it's`http.cookiejar` and not `http.cookieJar`.

Notice the un-captitalised `J.`

Comment: I did use the 2to3.py tool but it did not change the line in question. And yes, I did see the capitalization issue.

Comment: Strange. The docs say that the conversion should be automatic, maybe the script screwed up somewhere, hope you resolved your issue now. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the solution. The following seems to work:
cj = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()

Answer (score 0):

The library `cookielib` module has been renamed to `http.cookiejar` in **Python 3**, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/cookielib.html.

You may use the the `2to3` tool to convert your source code to Python 3, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html